# Can I stay at same level of greater rift?

Tags: diablo-iii

It seems i can either upgrade my keystone or upgrade my gem. Is there a way to get my current keystone back at the end of the greater rift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you only have the two options that you list. You can either proceed to the next level of greater lift (assuming you defeated the Greater Rift Guardian before time ran out), or choose to upgrade legendary gems three times.

Comment: booo that's too bad...

Comment: +1 Don't forget option 3 :) Leave and don't take either one of the benefits. But really, there is no way to keep the current one as you say.

Comment: Also worth noting: finishing too fast will cause you to jump ahead multiple levels.